# How to display a ref variable without using state in React?

Tags: reactjs

was wondering if there is any way to directly display the value of a variable from ref without using state, all the examples deal with "alerting" and alert works just fine, I'm trying to figure out to way to display it immediately as well. So, I am simply trying to display the value from the "name" here. Apologies for the x variable naming.

I assume it's not friendly to the DOM.

Thank you.

```
const UncontrolledExample = () => {
  const name = useRef();
  let x = '';

  const showValue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(name.current.value);
    x = name.current.value;
    return x;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="text" ref={name}/>
      </label>
      <button onClick={showValue}>
        Display value : {x}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use a ref and not state? The react way to display something new on the page is to set state.

Comment: It's for practice from a book I'm following, I assume it's to show it's not to be done, but I'm trying to be sure. Now I'm intrigued by it as well.

Comment: useRef will not cause a re-render, that's why you are seeing on alert but not on  view, You need to use useState for another re-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react, if you want the page to update, you must set state. Your tutorial seems to be showing you how to do uncontrolled components. If you want to keep the input as an uncontrolled component you can, but you still need a state for X. That would look like this:

```
const UncontrolledExample = () => {
  const name = useRef();
  const [x, setX] = useState('');

  const showValue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setX(name.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="text" ref={name}/>
      </label>
      <button onClick={showValue}>
        Display value : {x}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, you can turn the input into a controlled component. If you want the display value to only change when the button is pressed, you'll need two states:

```
const ControlledExample = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [x, setX] = useState('');

  const showValue = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setX(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="text" 
          value={inputValue} 
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <button onClick={showValue}>
        Display value : {x}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If they should always change simultaneously (ie, without the button), you just need one state:

```
const ControlledExample = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="text" 
          value={inputValue} 
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <p>Display value : {inputValue}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```